# When moving a folder, all references in that folder stop working

Tags: php

I have propel2.0 installed on windows and everything works. I now need to deploy it to my site, so I tested by moving everything to a different folder first.

folderstucture:

[image: folderstructure]

inside my config.php is a line

```
$serviceContainer = \Propel\Runtime\Propel::getServiceContainer();
```

but this gives me an error

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Propel\Runtime\Propel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php:2
```

I don't want to manualy add every reference in every file because that means that I will have to do everything manualy every time an update to propel is made.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using some autoloader? Is it pointing to the new folder? Also, it would be easier to understand your file/folder structure if you showed is as a tree view.

Comment: Is there any dumped container that contains a reference to your local document root?

Comment: I updated my post with a structure. I am not using an autoloader. I also dont know if there is a dumped container. How would i look for that?

Comment: `composer update` ?

Comment: the problem with that is that on my remote machine, I cannot use the commandline